# You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, view

i have :

```
 mContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout();
 mContainer.addView(nViews)
```

But i recive the error :

```
 The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()   
 on the child's parent first
```

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an important difference between [`removeAllViewsInLayout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViewsInLayout()) and [`removeAllViews()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()).

The former may not remove all the views, the latter will remove all the views. Unless you are doing your own logic to figure which views were removed in `removeAllViewsInLayout()`, you are likely trying to add duplicate views to your layout.

As a matter of fact, `removeAllViewsInLayout()` comes with this warning:

> Do not call this method unless you are extending ViewGroup and understand the view measuring and layout pipeline.

Based on your post, I am assuming that you are not extending ViewGroup and properly analyzing the measuring/layout pipeline, and thus should not be calling that method.

However, if `mContainer` is not actual parent of `nViews`, clearing `mContainer` will not suffice. In that case you have to remove `nViews` using `removeView()` method on it's real parent before you can add it to `mContainer`.

Comment: removeAllViews() => same error ; mContainer is the root LiniarLayout of my layout.xml

Comment: Where is `nViews` coming from? You haven't posted enough information to analyze the flow of why `nViews` would be getting added twice, but the error message is pretty clear that is what is happening.